# Different urls for front page depending on language

Tags: 7

I'm using entity translation module and want to have different urls for front page in accordance with languages.

For example:
front-eng
fr/front-page-for-france
pt/front-page-for-portugal
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your template file then you can page accoding to your choose language

```
  function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
        if ($vars['is_front']) {
            $langcode = $GLOBALS['language']->language;

            if ($langcode == "en") {
                drupal_goto('home');
            } elseif ($langcode == "fr") {
                drupal_goto('front-page-for-france pt');
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that for all languages the front is same and represented in page--front.tpl.php. Just need to redirect different url for seo purposes but open the same content.